# What is the IE equivalent to window.pageYOffet?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I tried `window.offsetTop` and a couple other things and syntaxes, no dice

Answer (score 1):

IE equivalents are [`document.body.scrollLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534617(VS.85).aspx) and [`document.body.scrollTop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534618(VS.85).aspx).